# Error in Pom File While creating a new STS project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Getting error in the Pom file while creating a new Spring Starter Project. Updated to the latest STS version 4.21.0 using the Compatible java version 17 but still the same error.
SS for reference ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHoga.png )

POM File Contents which is showing error:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>FormDetails</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FormDetails</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jarplugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

have uninstalled and installed couple of times but same issue, tried updating maven project as well. Please help!!

Comment: You need to be more sepcific with the error you're seeing - please include all error output from Maven.

Comment: The tag names in the `maven-jar-plugin.version` property don't match - is that intentional?

Comment: Why have you defined the property for maven-jar-plugin.version? What is the problem with that? Try to build your project on plain command line... not within your IDE...

Comment: Pls share error message